# Можно ли узнать имя выполняемой процедуры?

Tags: delphi

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста. Есть ли такая функция?

Comment: А давайте-ка вы лучше обрисуете саму общую проблему (лучше в отдельном вопросе), а мы все вместе подумаем как ее лучше решить.

Comment: Да проблема у меня пустяшная. Есть 8 комбобоксов, и соответственно 8 процедур ComboBox[цифра]Change. В каждой такой процедуре нужно извлечь цифру из названия. Я теперь сообразил - цифру можно извлекать из ComboBox[цифра].Name.

Comment: А еще лучше не мучать название, а положить номер в поле `Tag`. И в обработчике просто вытаскивать `Sender.Tag`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет такой функции нет.
так как исполняется не ваш код а уже откомпилированный в машинный язык

Answer (score 1):

Если запустить приложение под дэбагером - то в принципе можно, если знаете *asm*.
Но если интересует именно возможность узнать имя выполяемой функции из программы на Delphi, особенно из той-же самой в которой вы хотите посмотреть имя выполняемой функции - то тут точно ни как (если не писать свой дизассемблер и отладчик).

Comment: Нет, мне нужно в самой процедуре узнать ее имя (оно содержит цифру, вот она-то мне и нужна).

Comment: Имя процедуры даже под дебагером не узнает